# QGraphicsTextItem RightToLeft text

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qgraphicsscene, qgraphicstextitem

I have to write some Farsi texts to a `QGraphicsTextItem` , but I can't find how I can make `QGraphicsTextItem` to write RightToLeft!.
Can any one help me?.

I tryed this way but it didn't work for me:

```
class DiagramTextItem(QtGui.QGraphicsTextItem):

def __init__(self, parent=None, scene=None):
    super(DiagramTextItem, self).__init__(parent, scene)
    doc =QtGui.QTextDocument ('''شسشس
                              یییییگ''')
    txtOpt = QtGui.QTextOption()
    txtOpt.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)
    doc.setDefaultTextOption(txtOpt)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you could use [QTextOption.setTextDirection](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qtextoption.html#setTextDirection) with [Qt.RightToLeft](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#LayoutDirection-enum).

But note that you may need to set the direction *before* you set the text:

```
class DiagramTextItem(QtGui.QGraphicsTextItem):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, scene=None):
        super(DiagramTextItem, self).__init__(parent, scene)
        doc = QtGui.QTextDocument()
        txtOpt = QtGui.QTextOption()
        txtOpt.setTextDirection(QtCore.Qt.RightToLeft)
        doc.setPlainText('''شسشس
                         یییییگ''')
```

If that doesn't work, try setting the cursor on the `QGraphicsTextItem`:

```
class DiagramTextItem(QtGui.QGraphicsTextItem):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, scene=None):
        super(DiagramTextItem, self).__init__(parent, scene)
        cursor = self.textCursor()
        format = cursor.charFormat()
        format.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.RightToLeft)
        cursor.setFormat(format)
        self.setTextCursor(cursor)
        self.setPlainText('''شسشس
                          یییییگ''')
```

Comment: no , it changed somethings but not still that what i need ! first line must be at right ! not left ! look at this pic , ty http://ma3ta.persiangig.com/programing/text.png

Comment: @SepehrMohammadPour. I have updated my answer with some further suggestions.